# how to avoid image to be cut off when generating pdf using jspdf?

Tags: jspdf, page-break

I want to avoid image to be cut off at page break points when generating pdf using jspdf library.

I already have tried these methods below but I couldn't solve this problem

1. putting  into

   so that image is treated as text -> it doesn't work.
2. applying to "page-break-inside:avoid" css property -> it doesn't work.
3. calculating space of bottom of the page and decide to put image to current page or next page. -> it doesn't work.
4. applying to jspdf option "autoPaging:text" -> it only works to text, not to image.

I have no idea if there are another ways to solve this problem.